# Markdown image-hyperlink formatting doesn't work

Tags: html, github, hyperlink, markdown

I was trying to use an image as *hyperlink*, in a markdown file in **Github**. As far as I know HTML tags can be used normally in markdown, so I used the `<a href>` tag with the `<img src>` tag inside, like this:

```
<a href="https://github.com/arindal1">
    <img src="https://github.com/arindal1/arindal1/assets/110285827/b162e876-2100-42dd-8c5c-75321e2b39b3" alt="github" width="40px">
</a>
```

- The image *source* is from a site called [IconFinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/), of a GitHub icon.
- I copied the image link from the site to use it, in the markdown file as an hyperlink to my **Github** profile.

The **problem** I'm facing is that, the `<a href>` doesn't work like it's supposed to. The *img* tag is inside the *anchor* tag but hovering over the images shows the image link, not the *href source*, and likewise clicking the image, opens up to the images source link:

`https://github.com/arindal1/arindal1/assets/110285827/b162e876-2100-42dd-8c5c-75321e2b39b3`
**instead of** `https://github.com/arindal1`.

I was previously using the same *anchor* and *img* combination for using images as hyperlinks, but I was uploading the images into a folder inside my repo, say `img/..`, and using it like:

```
<a href="https://github.com/arindal1">
    <img src="img/github.png" alt="github" width="40px">
</a>
```

This worked like expected, clicking the image opened up my **Github** profile.

I also tried using markdown syntax `![image](image_link)` but nothing worked for the icon links.
I'm sure the *https://* is there, so that's not the issue, can someone help me with this?